# Android- Image resize and cropping

Tags: android, image, resize, crop

I am using a library to choose an image from the gallery and crop it. However, I found an option for rotating the image as well.
[Here's the link](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/issues/42)
to the library I'm using.

In my code I'm accessing the provided functionality similar to the example given in the library. There are 2 questions I have.

1. The Image I choose from the gallery is always rotated in some order (either clock or anti-clock) upon searching for solution I understood that this is caused due to large size of the Image. But, cant find a good solution to resize the image, given that I have to use this library.
2. Though the Image rotation works fine, and I'm able to crop the image properly, but the resultant cropped image is still rotated with the cropped part section equivalent to what I cropped. Sorry, I can't post Images due to less repo points.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, So I couldn't find any easy way to do this. 
But there is an old repository on git that I looked into ([Click here](https://github.com/biokys/cropimage)) and tweaked a little to get what I wanted. I tweaked the aspect ratio and the layout design to make it look good!

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to deterimne the rotation of the image in your gallery. You need to pass in the path to the image you get back as a result from the picker.

```
public static int getRotationFromBitmapFile(String filePath) {
        ExifInterface exifInterface = null;
        try {
            exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Logger.d("Unable to read ExifInterface from file", e);
        }

        if (exifInterface != null) {
            int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    return 180;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    return 270;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    return 90;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        //Could not read or information not present, use 0?!!
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Umm, It is always returning zero. How does applications like whatsapp or facebook handle this? Any clue regarding that?

Comment: This code is copy-paste from our project. It works there like a charm. We allow user to change his profile photo by allowing him to take an image with his camera. After he has done that, we scale that image down and compress it, rotate it according to the function above and finally upload it to the server

Comment: You should check if the exception is raised, then the photo does not contain this information.

Comment: Okay, Rotation is not an issue.. after choosing the image i'm able to rotate the image but that rotation reverts after cropping. So, probably the issue is with the crop? And the weird thing is, the cropped part is exactly what i wanted to crop.. its just that it rotates back to that angle.

Comment: How are you cropping the image. Are you passing in a bitmap or a path to original file? If you are passing the file path, it will load that image and not the one you rotated. You rotating it after it's cropped would seem to fix the issue

Comment: Okay, let me try that!